# How to get the binary build and source code tarball for JDK 8?

Tags: java

A JDK installation includes a `src.zip`. But it does not contain all the source code files. For example, it does not have `Unsafe.java`. What I want is the source code which can be used to build JDK.

Since Oracle does not provide the source code for its JDK, I want to find the source code for OpenJDK. [JDK 8 Update Releases Wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/jdk8u/Main) contains the Mercurial repositories which I can get the source. But it is troublesome. First, I am not familiar with Mercurial. Second, Mercurial forest extension is used. So I wan to get the source code tarball which includes everything.

In `Releases` part of [JDK 8 Update Releases Wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/jdk8u/Main), I find `8u232-b09 (GA), October 15th 2019 [Release] [Tag] [Binaries]`:

1. I can click `Binaries` to download the binary build.
2. I can click `Release` to open
   https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2019-October/010452.html
   where I can find the tarball link
   https://openjdk-sources.osci.io/openjdk8/openjdk8u232-ga.tar.xz.
   Then I can use the tarball link to do the download.

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

You approach is correct as it downloads the sourcecode as a tarball.

You can also get the source code as git repository clone from GitHub  https://github.com/openjdk/jdk .